# How to get an output of only 2 numbers by getting the sum and have it output my elif number first

Tags: python

I enter `DegreeDays([67, 78, 96, 80, 75, 62, 53])` and it gives me `[0, 16, 7]`. I need it to output `[7, 16]`. It should be outputting the sum of my if statement and the sum of my elif.

```
def DegreeDays(val1):
    results = []
    for val in val1:
        if 79 < val < 97:
            results.append(96-val)


        elif 52 < val < 61:
            results.append(60-val)


    return results
```

Answer (score 0):

For your expected results as mentioned

I am assuming you need sorted list that can be easily done with `.sort()` method present in python list

so before returning `results.sort()` and then `return results.sort()`

or you can do `return sorted(results)`

To skip the 0 numbers from your list you can either change the range in which you are checking to `if 79 < val < 96:`

so your final code will be like:

```
def DegreeDays(val1):
    results = []
    for val in val1:
        if 79 < val < 96:
            results.append(96-val)


        elif 52 < val < 61:
            results.append(60-val)


    return sorted(results)
```

But if you want your `second condition` results to appear first you will have to either 
1. pass sorted list to the function
2. sort the list you are getting in your function

for the second point you will have add `val1.sort()` or if you dont want to modify the the list passed do:

```
def DegreeDays(val1):
    results = []
    modifiedVals = sorted(val1)
    for val in modifiedVals:
        if 79 < val < 96:
            results.append(96-val)


        elif 52 < val < 61:
            results.append(60-val)


    return results
```

This should fix the issue

Comment: This does not work. Lists are mutable, `list.sort()` returns `None`

Comment: I dont think thats what he said at all ... he wants values from the elif branch to come before values in the primary if branch

Comment: @Azsgy I was modifying and updating the answer the time you saw, fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

The results [0, 16, 7] are accurate and based on your input list.
I have added some prints for you to see what is going on in your code.

```
def DegreeDays(val1):
    results = []
    for val in val1:
        if 79 < val < 97:
            print("number is {0} and in range (79-97)\n append {1} to results".format(val,96-val))
            results.append(96-val)


        elif 52 < val < 61:
            print("number is {0} and in range (52-61)\n append {1} to results".format(val,60-val))
            results.append(60-val)


    return results

print (DegreeDays([67, 78, 96, 80, 75, 62, 53]))
```

If you really want 7,16 then adjust your input list or use `sorted`
this is a example [67, 78, 53, 80, 75, 62, 50] list that will give you [7,16]

**Output**

```
number is 96 and in range (79-97)
 append 0 to results
number is 80 and in range (79-97)
 append 16 to results
number is 53 and in range (52-61)
 append 7 to results
[0, 16, 7]
```